# DynamoDB query to get items based on IDs from other table

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have two tables in DynamoDB:

- Articles

  - _id
  - title
  - text
- ArticleTag

  - articleId
  - tag

One article can have many tags such as "php", "html", "design" and "erlang".

I would like to **query** my articles table and paginate only through those that:

- Have some specific tags

or

- Do not have one specific tag

How would I do this most efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer to your question doesn't really lie in the DynamoDB schema design. DynamoDB is not necessarily right/best tool for the job, though you can use it to model your problem.

Think of DynamoDB as a distributed, scalable hash-map. If you think of it this way you'll realize that the way you need to model the tags-to-articles mapping is by storing references to articles, keyed by the tag.

so perhaps:

```
articles table:
  id (partition key),
  title,
  text,
  tags

tags table:
  tag (partition key),
  article id (sort key)
```

Notice that the `articles` table above has a list of tags that were applied to each article, and the same information is also stored in the `tags` table. This goes against the best practices of normalizing your schema you might be familiar with from relational databases. But DynamoDB is a non-relational database so you have to structure your data differently.

It's important to mention that the schema as presented above will very likely lead to partition hot-spotting due to the fact that there will be some popular tags which will correspond to lots of articles, while the majority of tags will have very low cardinality. A potential strategy to deal with this problem might be to sub-partition the tag-space.

But you might have better results by combining DynamoDB with another technology, such as Elastic Search.

Comment: Thanks you, that makes sense. Would you suggest the "tags" field to be an array? I am a bit unsure on how to write the QueryCondition for plucking specific articles by tag.

Comment: The tags attribute on the articles table could be a string set. But that is not how you query for articles in a tag. That  is what the tags table is for. There you simply have to query the tag you are intersted in. Where things get interesting is if you need to query by more than one tag. In that case you need a join and DynamoDB doesn't do joins. You'll have to do the join on the client, or get "creative"